# Css3 transition queue

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to queue css transition with same properties. Basically I want to translate an element to certain position (so transition duration 0) before I make another translate.

This is a mockup, click on move (box should move 100px right, before translate 100px left)

1. this doesnt work because second transition overwrites first?

https://jsfiddle.net/aqwaypoh/3/

2. This works (I needed transition duration non zero (0.01) otherwise transitionend doesnt fire).

https://jsfiddle.net/dpv3xzth/5/

There is another problem that transition end fires 2 times on chrome, but I could fix that, I was just wondering is there a better way to write this?

I would prefer if I could write this without end event or timer if possible?

```
<div class="box"></div>
<a href="#" class="move">move</a></a>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Update:**

You can use CSS3 `animation` property with `@keyframes`.

```
.box.animate {
  animation: move 2s;
}

@keyframes move {
  0% {
    transform: translate(100px);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translate(0px);
  }
}
```

And to make the box move you can add class `animate` to your element. Or you can set `animation` property yourself in javascript, it's up to you.

```
box.addClass('animate')
```

**jsfiddle:** https://jsfiddle.net/aqwaypoh/7/

Comment: This is wrong. After I click move, box needs to move to 100px left with transform in 0 sec, then start transform to 0px left in 0.5 sec. This would be like box.stop().css('left','100px'); then box.stop().animate({ 'left': 0px'}).....

Answer (score 0):

Adding a timeout on the second condition gives you what you want I believe.

```
var box = $('.box'),
  move = $('.move').click(function() {
    box.css({
      "transform": "translate(100px)",
      'transition-duration': '0s'
    });

    setTimeout(function(){
       box.css({
         "transform": "translate(0px)",
         'transition-duration': '0.5s'
       });
   }, 1);
  })
```